# Joomla 3.2 Registered Date and Last Visited Date

Tags: joomla

Quick question..does any know how to remove the "Registered Date" and "Last Visited Date" from the User Profile once they have logged in? I was able to remove the basic settings, but can't figure out how to remove those 2? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't believe this is an option within Joomla, therefore you will have to perform a template override. More information on this can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: That makes sense because I checked everywhere and found nothing. Thanks for your help..

Comment: No worries. You should make an answer with your template override after and accept it to mark as solved. It may help people in the future if they have the same question